# parameter inside a jsonpath expression in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonpath, json-path-expression

How can I use a parameter within a JSONPath expression in a PostgreSQL SQL query?

I want to query something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE jsondata @@ '$.pathto.array[*].** ? (@.someproperty == ":VALUE").anotherproperty != null';
```

I tried:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE jsondata @@ '$.pathto.array[*].** ? (@.someproperty == "1").anotherproperty != null';
```

This query worked, but I can't use it with a bind parameter ("1").

Answer (score 1):

Using any JSONB functions in the `WHERE` clause (such as `jsonb_path_match`, `jsonb_path_query`,  `jsonb_path_exists`) preclude the use of indexes.

When both parameterization and indexing support are needed, use the [JsQuery](https://github.com/postgrespro/jsquery) extension.

Comment: Could you provide some example with jsQuery using parametrization?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`jsonb_path_match(target jsonb, path jsonpath, vars jsonb)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.5.11.2.2.18.1.1.1) and pass your variables in the third parameter, `vars`, as a `jsonb` literal or in `jsonb_build_object()`: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/XbqQgIOT)

```sql
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE 
jsonb_path_match(
      jsondata
    , '$.pathto.array[*].** ? (@.someproperty == $var).anotherproperty != null'
    , jsonb_build_object('var',your_variable_here) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this approach , it will let you use the parameter within jsonpath expression.

```
-- Defining a parameterized query with a placeholder for the value
PREPARE my_query (jsonb) AS
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE jsonb_path_query(
    jsondata,
    '$.pathto.array[*].** ? (@.someproperty == $1).anotherproperty != null',
    'true'
);

-- Executing the prepared query with the actual value for :VALUE
EXECUTE my_query('1'); -- Replace '1' with the actual value you want to use

-- Deallocating the prepared query when done
DEALLOCATE my_query;
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: The idea is good, but it's syntactically incorrect. You can't use an SRF in WHERE.